# bitnami kafka GCP mounted driver disappeared /bitnami/

Tags: bitnami

We setup a Bitnami kafka cluster (2 broker 1 zookeeper) on Google Cloud's Computer Engine.
After restarted the broker, one of the broker's bitnami kafka drive was unmounted.

Working broker:

```
kafka-cluster-demo-kafka-0:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           370M  5.0M  365M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       9.7G  2.7G  6.5G  30% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      124M  7.9M  116M   7% /boot/efi
**/dev/sdb         49G   53M   47G   1% /bitnami**
tmpfs           370M     0  370M   0% /run/user/1582053158
lumo_gftdevgcp_com@kafka-cluster-demo-kafka-0:~$ cd /bitnami/
lumo_gftdevgcp_com@kafka-cluster-demo-kafka-0:/bitnami$ ls
**kafka**  lost+found
lumo_gftdevgcp_com@kafka-cluster-demo-kafka-0:/bitnami$
```

**Issue broker:**

```
kafka-cluster-demo-kafka-1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           370M  256K  370M   1% /run
/dev/sda1       9.7G  4.5G  4.8G  49% /
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           740M     0  740M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda15      124M  7.9M  116M   7% /boot/efi
```

As you can there is no show of `/bitnami`

Anyone know how to remount the drive and why it disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Could you check your PVC and check if they are bound? It is really weird I didn't see that before